# Cannot access sqlite database created in cordova app via sqllite shell from android emulator

Tags: android, sqlite, cordova

I create a sqlite database in apache cordova with the cordova sqlite plugin like this

```
var db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({name: "mydb"});

db.transaction(function(tx) {

    tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mytable (id integer primary key, content text)');
});

db.transaction(function(tx) {
        tx.executeSql("insert into mytable values(1,'text')");
    }
})
```

I let it run on an android emulator, that provides access via shell:

```
    $ adb shell
```

I go to the path of my app

```
cd /data/data/nameofmyapp/databases
```

I can see, when I enter

```
ls
```

that I have a file mydb.db in the folder.

I enter

```
sqlite3 mydb
```

when I enter

```
.schema
```

I get just

```
CREATE TABLE android_metadata (locale TEXT);
```

(not the description of mytable what I would expect)
when I enter

```
select * from mytable;
```

I get nothing, like an empty result.

Why?

Comment: are you entering `sqlite3 mydb` command in the directory where the file is loctated? Also you can try to specify the full name of the file with the extension `sqlite3 mydb.db` and see if it works.

Comment: yes, but that does not make any difference.

Comment: I do not remember exactly how I solved it, but I think that I finally skipped working with the emulator and worked on an external tablet only. That seemed to cause fewer problems.